# Nail gun driver doesn't return after firing

Tags: tools

The hammer on my Bostitch SB 1664 fails to return to fire position. Did take out a wrong size nail since the jam it has failed. Can you tell me what the problem is?
Thanks, Owen S

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful, Air pressure for the supply ? is there a water separator? is the gun new or used. Was there any damage to the slide when you removed the wrong nail?

Comment: Are you sure that part of the nail isn't still jammed in the plunger slot?

Comment: Air pressure is set at 80 lbs. used gun, I can move slide back and forth with my fingers, no sign of damage.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the supply air pressure is within the pressure range specified by the manufacturer. If the supply pressure is too low, there may not be enough pressure built up to return the piston to the firing position.

Also make sure that all the vents are clear, and unobstructed.  If the vents are blocked, it could increase the resistance on the returning piston.  This added resistance, can prevent the piston from returning to the firing position.